# Centos8 undefined symbol: EVP_KDF_ctrl, version OPENSSL_1_1_1b

Tags: unix, centos8, undefined-symbol, ldd, libcrypto

while running ssh command on CentOs8 server getting below error message.

```
/usr/bin/ssh: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3: undefined symbol: EVP_KDF_ctrl, version OPENSSL_1_1_1b Connection closed

ldd ssh linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc21fa000) libcrypto.so.1.1 =>
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f8041dd4000) libdl.so.2 =>
/usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8041bd0000) libutil.so.1 =>
/usr/lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f80419cc000) libz.so.1 =>
/usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f80417b4000) libcrypt.so.1 =>
/usr/lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f804158b000) libresolv.so.2 =>
/usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f8041373000) libselinux.so.1 =>
/usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f8041148000) libgssapi_krb5.so.2 =>
/usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f8040ef3000) libkrb5.so.3 =>
/usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f8040c09000) libk5crypto.so.3 =>
/usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f80409f2000) libcom_err.so.2 =>
/usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f80407ee000) libc.so.6 =>
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8040429000) libpthread.so.0 =>
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8040209000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f804257c000) libpcre2-8.so.0 =>
/usr/lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f803ff85000) libkrb5support.so.0 =>
/usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f803fd74000) libkeyutils.so.1 =>
/usr/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f803fb70000)

/usr/lib64 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 May 4 2022 libcrypto.so.10 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.2o 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2521136 May 4 2022 libcrypto.so.1.0.2o 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Nov 10 2022 libk5crypto.so.3 -> libk5crypto.so.3.1 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Nov 10 2022 libk5crypto.so -> libk5crypto.so.3.1 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 96280 Nov 10 2022 libk5crypto.so.3.1 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov 30 2022 libbd_crypto.so.2 -> libbd_crypto.so.2.0.0 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 48824 Nov 30 2022 libbd_crypto.so.2.0.0 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Feb 8 21:44 libcrypto.so.1.1 -> libcrypto.so.1.1.1k 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Feb 8 21:44 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1.1k 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3083672 Feb 8 21:45 libcrypto.so.1.1.1k

LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib64/:/opt/mqm91C/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64/
```

Also other Application specific paths are added in LD_LIBRARY_PATH which is not mentioned here.